# What is the difference between following sentences

Tags: tense, difference

I am bored (or any other adjective)
I got bored (or any other adjective)
I've got bored (or any other adjective)
I was bored (or any other adjective)
I've become bored (or any other adjective)

Answer (score 1):

1. I am bored: I am currently feeling bored.
2. I got bored: I became bored.
3. I've got bored: I have gradually become bored, and I am currently feeling bored.
4. I was bored: I was feeling bored earlier [and possibly I am no longer feeling bored].
5. Same as 3.

Comment: I mostly agree except for #2 - that one is strictly about the past, and implies nothing about how you currently feel.

Comment: @stangdon can you suggest me a better answer? I will definitely try to improve my answer on that basis...

Comment: I would simply say "2: I got bored: I became bored."